# Raising a base (which is a decimal) to a power yields false results

Tags: python, variables, decimal, calculator

This is a calculator for the sum of geometric series and my problem is that if  the base (r) is a decimal and is raised to any power > 1, I would get an incorrect result 5.5^2 is 25 it's 30.25

(to you editors out there, I don't know how to highlight code and for future convenience I would like to know how so it would really help if I got instructions on how to do that)

I've tried assigning the function "float" to the variables assuming that if python sees the variable as a decimal, maybe what's after the decimal point would be raised to the power as well.

```
a1 = int(float(input("First Term in Sequence")))
r = int(float(input("Rate of Change")))
n = int(float(input("Number of Terms")))


def a(r,n):
    global rn
    r = float(r)
    n = float(n)
    rn = r**n
    return rn
```

I expect the output to be correct:
As in 5.5^2 = 30.25

Not:
5.5^2 = 25

It's almost as though the code does not bother with what comes after the decimal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a1 = int(float(input("First Term in Sequence")))
r = int(float(input("Rate of Change")))
n = int(float(input("Number of Terms")))
```

Why are you turning your inputs to `int` here?

If you had typed-in `5.5`, it would become `5` here. After this even if you do `float(5)` you would still get `5.0` not `5.5`

So you're actually calculating `5.0 ** 2.0` == `25`

Comment: Thanks man, I'm pretty new to Python and coding in general so I didn't see a problem with having float and int there at the same time. But now I do, appreciate it :D